# windows ble interface - HCI_VS_MSFT_LE_Monitor_Advertisement examples?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-gatt, bluetoothlescanner

In the Microsoft Bluetooth DOCs, I see these HCI commands that can be sent to the BLE stack

SEE: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/bluetooth/microsoft-defined-bluetooth-hci-commands-and-events

- HCI_VS_MSFT_LE_Monitor_Advertisement
- HCI_VS_MSFT_LE_Cancel_Monitor_Advertisement

I can't find any examples of:

- Opening the driver
- Using the above to request advertisements
- Receiving the advertisements

Can anybody point me to an example?

Comment: This is microsoft specified HCI commands (not standard ones). They can be sent using DeviceIoControl. The commands can be implemented by the vendor (if vendor wants) but there is no any guarantee that they will be implemented ever. Also, there is no IOCTL define for that commands.

Comment: On Win 10 - there is a BLE stack -built in on my laptop, and I would presume that would respond to these IOCTLS? would it not?

Comment: No, it would not. Please, read the IOCTLs description you posted the link to. All described there in details.

Comment: I don't see that. What I see is: (A) I have a win10 laptop, with built in BLE, (B) There is a microsoft app that talks via some standard way to what ever BLE stack is on my machine. (C) It would do so in some standard way via the WinRT library and/or C# libraries. (D) Those libraries would be using some standard windows thing to talk to a generic stack.  Thus (E) I would expect those libraries to use these IOCTLs to talk to the stack. So why can't my app also use those IOCTLS also?  OR - are you saying that winrt and C# use a 100% unique and different way? That seems wrong headed.

Comment: Sorry, that's not IOCTL, its HCI. IOCTL for that HCI (if they are available for user-mode apps) is IOCTL_VENDOR_COMMAND (not sure how it is exactly named). Stack talks to device using HCI commands defined in Bluetooth Core specification v.4 (and above). Not using this MS specified commands.